# What is the maximum level that you can upgrade troops/spells to?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Just wondering, as I want to be able to plan ahead in the overall progress in my village.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maximum upgrade level varies depending on troop type:

**Standard Troops**

- Max Level = 10: Giants, Wizards, Barbarians, Archers Wall Breakers, Balloons
- Max Level = 9: P.E.K.K.A.'s, Dragons
- Max Level = 8: Goblins, Dragons, Baby Dragons
- Max Level = 7: Miners, Healers
- Max Level = 6: Healers
- Max Level = 5: Electro Dragon
- Max Level = 4:
- Max Level = 3: Yeti, Dragon Rider

**Dark Troops**

- Max Level = 10: Hog Riders, Golems, Minions
- Max Level = 9: Valkyries
- Max Level = 8: -
- Max Level = 6: Lava Hound, Ice Golems
- Max Level = 5: Witches, Bowlers
- Max Level = 3: Head Hunter

**Heroes**

- Max level = 80: Barbarian King, Archer Queen
- Max level = 50: Grand Warden
- Max level = 30: Royal Champion

**Spells**

- Max Level = 9: Lightning
- Max Level = 8: Heal
- Max Level = 7: Freeze, Clone
- Max Level = 6: Rage
- Max Level = 4: Jump, Invisibility Spell

**Dark Spells**

- Max Level = 8: Poison
- Max Level = 7: Skeleton
- Max Level = 5: Bat, Earthquake, Haste

**Siege Machines**

- Max Level = 4: Wall Wrecker, Battle Blimp, Stone Slammer, Siege Barracks, Log Launcher